# How to check if user has granted All file access permission in special app access in react native?

Tags: react-native

For my react native project i wanted to access all document files(.pdf, .xlsx, .docx etc) whether it is on internal storage or sd_card for which i enabled MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest and asked user to enable all_files_access in settings>apps>special_app_access as from android 11 there is no simple way to get this permission from inside app, now is there any way in react native to detect if the permission is enabled or not?

I have tried checking if READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted after enabling all files access from settings but it remains denied.

I have also tried using react-native-fs with which i could read directories and subDirectories but not files in them which according to new android guidelines is only possible after enabling all files access from within settings.

Comment: Have you considered using Expo and its FileSystem module that provides an API to request permission to access a directory (and its subdirectories)?  https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#requestdirectorypermissionsasyncinitialfileurl

Comment: @GregFenton i can try it but before i tried with react-native-fs which did give me access to FileSystem i could read directories and subdirectories but not files in them so i dont think it will work.

Comment: IMO, doing React-Native without using Expo is a tragedy.  Even the RN team recommends using Expo.

Comment: @GregFenton i tried using expo but it results the same.

Comment: This might be a better topic to discuss in the Expo Developer server on Discord rather than trying to triage on SO    https://discord.com/invite/expo

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution but i achieved what i wanted. what i did was android prohibts us to read/write files out of scoped storage without all files access so what i do in my project is i write a dummy file out of scoped storage after getting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission now writing this dummy file is only successfull when all files access is granted so if it throws error i show dialogue to user to grant this permission.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).